# Convert from twos-complement to decimal

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, radix

You might be familiar with twos-complement representation of signed integers. It is the binary integer representation most widely used today. What is less known are some of the other proposals for binary integer representation, including base -2. Base -2 shares the arithmetic conveniences of twos-complement, and is perhaps easier to describe. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)

An example: 1011 is 1*(-2)^3 + 0*(-2)^2 + 1*(-2)^1 + 1*(-2)*0 = -8 + 0 + -2 + 1 = -9

Input

The first number T (from 1 to 100) is the number of integers to convert from base -2 to base 10.

The next T numbers are the base -2 numbers (each 1 to 15 digits).

Note: numbers may be padded on the left with 0s.

Output

Output the signed base 10 representation of the numbers, separated by whitespace.

---

The following is my code in C++; it pretty much just uses the method in the example above with 1011. It works fine in my own test cases, but when I submit it on the online judge, it gave wrong answer. I think it might be overflow. Any suggestion on how to improve my code. Thank you!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
long long int convert (long long int base, long long int num){
long long int exp=0;
long long int output=0;
while (num != 0){
    long long int digit = num - 10*int(num/10);
    output += digit * pow(base, exp);
    exp++;
    num = int(num/10);


}
return output;
}
int main(){
int cases;
cin >> cases;
long long int input;
long long int base = -2;
cin >> input;
cout << convert(base, input); 
for (int i=1; i< cases; i++){
    cin >> input;
    cout << " " << convert(base, input);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A number is an abstract concept expressable (e.g.) with your fingers.

Arithmetics instruct on a representation of that abstract number in different ways called numbering systems.

So a number may be mapped to a string of digits or to a sequence of numbers if you like it more.

The function convert you defined, takes a number and a base and converts it to a number. So it doesn't give a representation of that number as a sequence of digits.

Comment: George: I don't get it. I'm supposed to convert the input from base -2 to base 10. What's wrong with printing out the number (in base 10)?

Comment: May be I didn't understood what is needed. Could you explain me exactly what input you have and what output you need ?

Comment: @George: it's an automatically-judged programming exercise. Beyond the description in the question, you don't get to know what the input is. Your program gets run on some machine you don't control.

Answer (score 2):

So as you say it the best think is to read the question:

"The first number T (from 1 to 100) is the number of integers to convert from base -2 to base 10."
It seems here that there is a number of integers to convert.

"The next T numbers are the base -2 numbers."

So there are T numbers that should be interpreted in base -2.

"Each of them has 1 to 15 digits. "

"Note: numbers may be padded on the left with 0s."

"Output

Output the signed base 10 representation of the numbers, separated by whitespace."

So you have T that has a value. Say e.g. that it is 34.
Ater that you have 34 numbers in base -2.
Each of them has from 1 to 15 digits. These may be padded on the left with 0.

So you must choose the representation of each number ( will it be a string ? ).

You must convert that 34 numbers represented in base -2 into base 10 and separate the 34 numbers with a space.